# Show / Hide contents base on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle a content DIV base on the selection of radio buttons.

HTML for radio button.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="account" id="yes" value="yes" checked>
      Yes, I have an existing account
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="account" id="no" value="no">
      No, I don't have an account
    </label>
</div>
```

Content DIV

```
<div id="account_contents">
    <p>This is account contents.......</p>  
</div>
```

This is how I tried it in jquery.

```
$('#no').bind('change',function(){
  $('#account_contents').fadeToggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
  $('#account_contents').find("input").val("");
  $('#account_contents').find('select option:first').prop('selected',true);
});
```

But it doesn't work for me correctly. Here I want to show this content DIV only if user don't have an account.

Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: I ran the code and it works well for me. `account_contents` fades in when you click "No". Did you include jquery?

Comment: Yes, but, to toggle out I want to click again on `#no`. This is not the way I need, It should be toggle out when click on `#yes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

seems you need .on('change') for radio buttons not just for one of them

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="account"]').on('change',function(){
  var ThisIt = $(this);
  if(ThisIt.val() == "yes"){
       // when user select yes
       $('#account_contents').fadeOut();
  }else{
       // when user select no
       $('#account_contents').fadeIn();
       $('#account_contents').find("input").val("");
       $('#account_contents').find('select option:first').prop('selected',true);
  }
});
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/f4onwt67/)

Answer (score 2):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.radio input[type="radio"]').on("click", function(){
            if($('.radio input[type="radio"]:checked').val() === "yes"){
                $("#account_contents").slideDown("slow");
            }else{
                $("#account_contents").slideUp("slow");
            }
          });
     });
```

Comment: by default add a css property on you block <div id="account_contents" style="display:none;" to hide this element

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31z7aa3c/embedded/result/) toggles `#account_contents` depending on which button you click:

This was how i tweaked the script:

```
  $('#no').bind('change',function(){
  $('#account_contents').fadeToggle(!$(this).is(':checked'));
  $('#account_contents').find("input").val("");
  $('#account_contents').find('select option:first').prop('selected',true);
});
$("#yes").bind("change", function() {
  $('#account_contents').fadeOut();
});
```